# Using switch case with context menu item click event

Tags: c#

I have a context menu with sub-menus that have a lot of items.So how can I use case switch or something like that for the click event of those items,instead of double clicking them from the designer?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send them to the same click event handler.

Then you can use the `sender` parameter to determine which object was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can double click on first one (arbitrary) and after copy the *name* of generated event handler and paste it in the `Click` property of any other `MenuItem` form `Property` window.